# Why does this suggested edit deviate from the original intent?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/875390) has been rejected due to the reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Of course I don't have an objective viewpoint here, but I think the suggested deleted lines don't contribute anything to the understanding of the OP. Every original intent of the post can be compacted as shown in my suggested edit; it is acceptable for a non-mathematician to have unconventional or personal interpretation in here. So why is this edit bad?

[image]

Comment: You did a lot more than improve formatting, remove thanks/greetings. Looks pretty drastic to me.

Comment: The most favorable of the comments given to you as a reason for rejecting the edit:  "*This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.*"  You're suggested edit does deviate from the asker's post.  The idea in editing another's post is not to write what *you* think the asker ought to have asked, rather what is asked, and all the context provided by the asker.  Questions get closed for lack of context! And I think you robbed the original post of a bit of the asker's context.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list of reasons why I found your edit undesirable.

- Changing the title from a statement to a question is a matter of taste. I don't like edits based on taste because they don't make the post easier to read or to find.
- You changed

> Now, I am confident with the mathematical definitions and all the formalism, and (more or less) I know all the main theorems.

to

> I know the main theorems and definitions of Fourier analysis

which is worse than just editing based on taste: it removes some information about the question authors background. Note the use of the adjective "mathematical" before "definitions" and the word "formalism" and the phrase "more or less". These all indicate to me that the author isn't greatly familiar with proof based mathematics.

- Additionally, these sentiments are no longer present after your edit:

> Pretend to be talking with someone smart, very curious but not very knowledgeable about mathematics.
>
> Having a truly physical interpretation of those concepts would be great!!
>
> I would really love to have some unconventional and "personal" interpretation/point of view.

which is the main reason I felt your edit went against the authors intent.

- Lastly, you added the [hilbert-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilbert-spaces) tag because...why?

Comment: I'll answer you point by point, but again, I'm aware that my favor to them could ultimately base on taste. 1) It seems that the community also favor a real question in title, since "choosing the right question is the key to getting the answer that you need" ([Should question titles be phrased as questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20005/260800))

Comment: 2) The author explicitly says that they are "**confident** with mathematical definitions and **all** the formalism", I don't understand why they couldn't be familiar with proof based mathematics. I think the phrases "more or less" and "not very knowledgeable" are just for staying humble. And even if the edit is overdone, an addition improvement on it is suffice. 3) It is acceptable for a non-mathematician to have unconventional or personal interpretation in here, so those bits are unnecessary. And even if the edit is overdone, an addition improvement on it is suffice.

Comment: 4) Is Hilbert transform not a subset of Hilbert space?

Comment: @Ooker In my experience, people who go to great pains to explain that they more or less know the formalism do it because they *don't* (but think they do). The question has some red flags for the reader that were removed by your edit. This is doubly so given the original final paragraph.